# base system device has yellow exclaimation mark

Tags: acer-aspire, acer-aspire-one

I just had windows 7 reinstalled as my computer crashed now my webcam wont take a picture or cant read my sd card. says base system device driver has a yellow exclaimation mark could this be the problem I have a acer aspire E1-531

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need drivers for a few devices.  If you have the CD that came with your computer, you can usually find drivers there.  Otherwise go to your manufacturers page at

http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers

Type in your model number and download / install the drivers.